# How to implement Emoji with Native MultiAutocompleteTextView?

Tags: android, emoji

I want to add Emoji with MultiAutocompleteTextView and want to send to server, so it should support with iOS and wen end also. so how can I use, I so some libraries but then only use to display emoji in local.

Answer (score 0):

Emoji are nothing but the special [UNICODES](http://unicode.org/standard/WhatIsUnicode.html), which are locally processed and shown as emoji.

Have a look at  : 
**Android**

- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/emoji-compat
- https://github.com/will5/EMOJITextView

I do not have any idea about the iOS, but it should be the same.